# Embedding images in a Rails Builder generated RSS feed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, paperclip

I'm currently building an RSS feed for my Rails application using Builder (the wealth of tutorials out there for doing it this way helped), but become a little bit stuck when it comes to adding an image alongside it (which has been uploaded via Paperclip), like a lot of the top publications do.

I'm currently using this to make the text appear as it should in a reader:

```
         xml.description do
           xml.cdata!page.description.gsub(/\n/, '<br />')
         end
```

So how would I go about including an image in the feed when I normally display them in a

```
  @page.assets.each do |asset|
```

block.

Thanks.